# Box-sizing:border-box not working on pseudo element

Tags: css, pseudo-element, border-box

I am trying to apply box-sizing:border-box to a pseudo element with no luck - the padding - necessary for the effect - is preventing the max width (or width) of the pseudo element from being 0 - it's always 0 + padding.

The element I want to apply it to is an `<a>` tag

```
<a class="button">Learn More</a>
```

And my css explicitly calls border-box on the element:

```
.button {
    font-family:helvetica;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #231f20;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding:12px 40px;
    position: relative;
}

.button:before {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    content:"Learn More";
    background-color:#231f20;
    max-width:0%;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:#fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding:12px 40px;
    transition:200ms ease-in;
}

.button:hover:before {
    max-width:100%; 
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/metaheavies/od6ko01b/

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what your desired effect is. But is this more the way you want it? https://jsfiddle.net/w59p8nbh/

Comment: Thanks Michaël - You've almost got it, apart from the flickering of the text color. If you remove the padding on the a and a:before element on my fiddle it works correctly - the white text of the :before element is fixed in place and is revealed smoothly on hover. However, padding + border cause the unwanted problem. I'll see if I can't get yours to work correctly.

Comment: Just a note - I'd really like to understand why the padding is affecting the box model - from what I know adding an explicit border-box should make it work correctly (i.e with max-width:0 you shouldn't see the black background at all)

Comment: Managed to get pretty close to what I wanted by taking Michael's code and adding a color transition on the :after element to make the transition much smoother. Still would really like to understand what's going on but this works for me.